# Javascript sum rows values is not working

Tags: javascript

I have the next javascript function which should sum all the hidden form object values (only for checked rows) and it is not working because it is not adding new values, only adds first value to the variable.
Look the code:

```
function SumarTotales(tableID)
{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var RowsSelected = 0;
    var vTotal=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) 
    {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) 
        {
            RowsSelected++;
            vTotal = vTotal + parseFloat(document.getElementById('Total'+chkbox.id).value).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('Totales').innerHTML='Fila(s) seleccionada(s): ' + RowsSelected + ' - Total a Reimputar: ' + parseFloat(vTotal).toFixed(2);
}
```

The hidden form objects has ids in the way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Total<%=rs("fieldName")%>" value="<%=rs("total")%>">
```

The javascript variable "vTotal" should return me the total values for every row selected. It is not doing the "sum" for some reason. It is returning me only the value regarding one row.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: why don't ya console log and see ?

Comment: Because for table you are using `getelementbyid` this will only get the first element. You need to use a class and then you can loop it since it will return a nodelist.

Comment: The line "parseFloat(document.getElementById('Total'+chkbox.id).value).toFixed(2);" is returning me the right values...I'm iterating well for every item in the table, the problem is that for some reason the variable "vTotal" is not accumulating the values I'm iterating through.